# условие которое работает только в денвере

Tags: php, mysql

Условие на количество неверных попыток входа. Почему в денвере работает условие IF а на сервере срабатывает ELSE ? В денвере увеличивается количество попыток а на сервере лишь добавляется новая запись с таким же IP

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['id']))
{
    $select = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ip FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'");
    $tmp = mysqli_fetch_row ($select);
    if ($ip == $tmp[0]) {
        $result52 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'");
        $myrow52 = mysqli_fetch_array($result52);
        $col = $myrow52[0] + 1;
        mysqli_query ($db, "UPDATE oshibka SET col=$col,date=NOW() WHERE ip='$ip'");
    }
    else {
        mysqli_query ($db, "INSERT INTO oshibka (ip,date,col) VALUES ('$ip',NOW(),'1')");
    }
```

В денвере ip 127.0.0.1 , на сервере 178.168.244. Обрезается ip? 4 же значения должно быть?

Поля  prntscr.com/bdu7zr на сервере, в денвере точно такие же

Comment: переменная `$ip`, откуда она берётся в вашем коде?

Comment: @MasterAlex $ip=getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
 if (empty($ip) || $ip=='unknown') {
  $ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
 }

Comment: это происходит даже если таблица пустая изначально на локалке?

Comment: @masterAlex Сначала была пустая, и просто добавляет новые записи

Comment: То есть на локалке так происходит: в пустой таблице создаётся запись сначала, а потом к ней добавляется +1 при каждом новом входе?

Comment: @masterAlex Именно так, при ложном входе, а на сервере просто новые записи

Comment: попробуйте такую функцию для определения IP: `function GetRealIp()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        return $ip;
    }`. У меня она без сбоев работала. Хотя если записи добавляется и IP есть, возможно, дело не в этом.

Comment: @masterAlex Видимо проблема не в этом(

Comment: Попробуйте после `else` добавить `mysqli_free_result($select); `

Comment: @MasterAlex Всё равно

Comment: Какой типо поля `ip`? Может, оно обрезается при вставке? И каждый раз заново вставляется и снова обрезается. В базу правильный ip сохраняется?

Comment: @jekaby http://prntscr.com/bdu7zr вот что на сервере, в денвере точно такое же, в денвере ип 127.0.0.1 , на сервере  178.168.244. только меня смущает точка в конце. Значит он и правда обрезается? Что делать? 4 же значения должно быть?

Comment: @Евгений, а у вас случаем в базе не стоит ограничение на количество символов для поля `varchar(12)`? может из-за этого обрезает

Comment: @MasterAlex Ну я конечно и поржал xD 
Всё заработало, добавляйте ответ. Только вопрос, раз оно обрезало до . то почему все равно не прибавлялось? Я про то что ip все равно же одинаковый и обрезает оно до все того же символа, так почему не работало?

Comment: @Евгений, 127.0.0.1 это 9 символов, поэтому не обрезалось

Comment: @MasterAlex Я не про денвер

Comment: @Евгений, так определяло-то оно IP верно и полностью, а обрезало уже при добавлении в базу, из базы доставало обрезанное значение и сравнивало его с нормальным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал сборный ответ из комментов, вроде всё верно написал:

В базе для поля `ip` стоит тип `varchar(12)`, поэтому при добавлении данных с локального компьютера добавляется IP `127.0.0.1` и это 9 символов, далее всё в порядке, всё работает.

А на сервере IP стал больше, например, `178.168.244.38` и при добавлении в базу обрезается до `178.168.244.`. Дальше это значение сравнивается с  `178.168.244.38` выдаёт `false` и добавляет новую строчку, которая тоже обрезается.